# How to apply stylesheet to an attribute of a class in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

I want to apply a stylesheet to an object which is defined in a class. I tried setObjectName but it doesn't work. Is there any way? Thanks in advance.

```
 self.but = QPushButton(text, self)
 self.but.setObjectName('but')
 self.but.setStyleSheet(open("mystylesheet.css").read())
```

And hear is my css

```
SwitchPageButtons#but {
    border :1.5px dashed black;}
```

Comment: please provide a [mre], try `SwitchPageButtons > QPushButton#but {`

Comment: That selector means: use this border for widgets of class `SwitchPageButtons` that have "but" as object name. Clearly, your button doesn't match that requirement. So, if your class is named SwitchPageButtons, then do what eyllanesc suggested, otherwise don't use invalid selectors and [read more about their usage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types).